# Por que está dando esse erro no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

eu já baixei e instalei o emulador, mas ta dando esse erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que quer dizer com "instalei o emulador"? É que além de instalar o emulador tem de criar, pelo menos, um dispositivo(AVD).

Comment: sim, eu ja criei o dispositivo avd, mas sempre aparece essa mensagem "unknown avd"

Comment: Suponho que já clicou na seta do combobox para verificar se há mais opções.

Comment: sim, já cliquei, aparece uma caixa vazia.

Comment: Faço o update do Emulador e do Intel x86 Accelerator, como sugerido na parte inferior da IDE.

Comment: Já atualizei o android studio ontem....